# Should I transfer my ADA to the latest wallet when a new era become available?

Tags: ada

I haven't been part of a new Era change but when a new era become avaiable, should I transfer my ADA to the latest wallet? i.e. from a Shelley to a Goguen wallet.

What is the process that I should perform and risks involved?

What happen if I don't do this?

Comment: Good and valid question. This was necessary for Byron to Shelley but most likely will not be the case going forward. See Marek's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing you need to do, thanks to [the hard fork combinator](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/explore-cardano/what-is-a-hard-fork-combinator.html), hard forks are entirely transparent to the users!